# 1 of 6 radiators doesn't get hot

Tags: heating, boiler, radiator

Situation:

- 5 out of 6 radiators never fail to get hot.
- For the 1 defective radiator, the pipe south of the valve is ice cold leading me to believe its not an issue with air in the radiator.
- 3 out of 6 radiators are on the same floor as the defective one and work fine leading me to believe its not a pressure problem.
- I bled the defective radiator.

Perceived Problem:

- Unknown

Proposed Solution:

- Unknown

[image]

***20221118 Update:***

- I bled it for some time.

[image]

- The right side became very hot. I turned the valve on the left side multiple times and I observe it doesn't move left or right. This leads me to believe that the knob is defective and it the root cause of stopping flow.
  [image]

Comment: With no flow, the pipe will be cold, so that does not prove lack of an air bubble. It just proves something is preventing flow here. They get hot from water flowing, and if water doesn't flow, they are cold. Presumably you've checked that the valve is open? Since you bled it, how much (if any) air did you get out, doing that?

Comment: Ty @Ecnerwal for your comment its helpful. No air was observed coming out. However I let it bleed for a good amount of time with a small bucket and it became hot on that side where I bled it.

Comment: The valve is probably broken.   You can turn the knob, but it's disconnected from the 'gate'.   It looks like it's going to be a ***** to remove.

Comment: Is there a valva at the other end that needs opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it warms after bleeding a long time, that does suggest valve is closed (or pipe is blocked) and the bleed is letting it heat be running water into it backwards. Valves are the right place to start, first making sure they're open, then if necessary removing caps to see if water is reaching them (messy!)

Comment: Had a plumber resolve the issue. I failed to put the valve in the open position. The stopper was defective so I couldn't tell what was the open position.

Answer (score 1):

The inlet pipe can fail to get hot when no hot water is going through the pipe leading up to it.

There are a few possibilities here.

It's possible the valve is clogged or stuck shut. Fixing that could be as simple as whacking the valve a few times while actuating it or replacing it.

It's also possible there is a air lock or clog in a high point upstream of the valve or downstream of the radiator that doesn't bleed easily. Fixing this is best done by closing all other radiator valves and then turning on the circulation pump. This should be strong enough to push through that air-lock bubble. A clog is a lot harder to fix.

Comment: Thanks. Because the valve fails to move to the left or right when I give it a good amount of turns, I think the valve is messed up. Unless I'm wrong in presuming that the valve should observably move to the right and left to indicate that its opening. Like a screw.

Comment: you could check against the other valves, though some may be stuck open